# Understanding Protobuf-net serialization and deserialization of properties

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm doing some tests with the Protobuf-net serializer and was experimenting with the serialization of properties.  Basically i wanted to store a dictionary(string, int)  as a dictionary(string, string)  and then on deserialization convert the (string, string) back to a (string, int). However, much to my surprise it goes through the getter on TestDictionary on deserialization (and then threw a null reference exception) which confused me a lot. I would think it goes through the setter on deserialization. So, essentially I'm not sure how property serialization is supposed to function. The simple test class I wrote is below:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Class1
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int test;
    public Dictionary<string, int> testDictionary;
    //public Dictionary<string, string> testDictionaryString;
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    private string test2;
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    private string test3;
    [ProtoMember(5)]
    private string test4;

    public Class1()
        {}

    public Class1(int test)
    {
        this.test = test;
            this.testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < test; i++)
        {
            this.testDictionary.Add("a" + i.ToString(), i);
        }
        test2 = (test + 1).ToString();
        test3 = (test + 2).ToString();
        test4 = (test + 3).ToString();
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> TestDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> temp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in this.testDictionary)
            {
                temp.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value.ToString());
            }
            return temp;
        }
        set
        {
            testDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in value)
            {
                testDictionary.Add(pair.Key, Convert.ToInt32(pair.Value));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Deserializing probably does something like `obj.TestDictionary[key] = value` for each key/value pair - it mutates the dictionary returned by your getter. Your approach would only work if it deserialized the dictionary first and then assigned the result to your property.

Comment: It is much cheaper to store `int` than `string`, btw, so I would **not** do this in real code. If you're just experimenting with the API: fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of serialization, dictionaries are treated just like lists.
You can *imagine* the default list serialization as something like (assuming that there is a `set` available):

```
var list = obj.TheProperty;
if(list == null) {
    list = new TheListType();
    obj.TheProperty = list;
}
do {
    list.Add(DeserializeTheItemType(reader));
} while ({still that field})
```

However, you can influence it. Simply adding `OverwriteTrue = true` may be sufficient for your needs:

```
[ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
public Dictionary<string, string> TestDictionary {...}
```

This should now do something more like:

```
var list = new TheListType();
do {
    list.Add(DeserializeTheItemType(reader));
} while ({still that field})
obj.TheProperty = list;
```

An important consequence here, however, is that `Merge` will no longer work in the usual expected way.

As a side note: your `get`/`set` should probably pass `null`s through, so that if `testDictionary` is `null`, `TestDictionary` returns `null`; and if `TestDictionary` is *set* to `null`, then `testDictionary` is set to `null`.